AWS IOT Job to increase Thing Shadow reported Variable
How would one create a Job that runs daily that just increases the reported variable of a thing shadow.
This means that if I have a variable called "counter" and its reported value is "11", I want the job to set the desired value to "12" (11+1) and would do this daily to keep increasing the "counter" variable.
